# The relationship between Kronig-Penney model and one-dimensional single atom chain model

Tags: solid-state-physics

How the Kronig-Penney relationship shows that

1. each energy band dispersion relationship is equal to satisfy $E\left(k+K_{h}\right)=E(k)$,
2. when $V_0$ is negative, the model is a good description of the movement of single electrons in the dimensional atom chain .

Kronig-Penney relationship is $\cos k a=\frac{m a V_{0}}{\hbar^{2}} \frac{\sin \alpha a}{\alpha a}+\cos \alpha a,\ $ $ \alpha^2 = 2 m E / \hbar^{2}$

My idea for the first question is to construct and draw a diagram to illustrate, but the second question has no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could first solve for the bound state of a single negative $V_0$ well, and then treat them as states of the atoms.